# Speed up basic slow google script for spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

I've created a simple script which iterates over the active (selected) range and checks if the cell value is less than 0. If it is, it makes the cell red, otherwise green! It works fine, but takes a long time (over a minute) to run on a small sheet (26rows x 30columns)

Is there anyone anyone can see to speed this up?

```
function colourize() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();

  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      if( range.getCell(i,j).getValue() < 0 ) {
        range.getCell(i,j).setBackground('#ea9999');
      } else {
        range.getCell(i,j).setBackground('#b6d7a8');
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This looks like a good application for [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/78413?hl=en).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it at array level like this :

```
function colourize() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var BGColors = range.getBackgrounds();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <values[0].length; j++) {
      if(values[i][j] < 0 ) {
        BGColors[i][j]='#ea9999';
      } else {
        BGColors[i][j]='#b6d7a8';
      }
    }
  }
  range.setBackgrounds(BGColors)
};
```

Comment: I think that `var BGColors = range.getBackgrounds();` is being used as a shorthand to get a correctly-sized array for the later call to `.setBackgrounds()`. Is that right? If so, this could be even faster if you just overwrote `values` with the colors, and used it to `.setBackgrounds()`.

Comment: you're probably right, I looked for simplicity and ease of understanding. And it's already soooo fast that I'm not sure one can feel any difference ;-)

Comment: But remember this rule in racing: second place is first loser!

Comment: Probably not worth it but one way to make it even faster is to detect the first and last row that will change colors. Then just setBackgrounds only to that subset of the array. It might make q difference if your array has many rows.